# how copy constructors work

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert> // for assert

class IntArray
{
private:
int m_length = 0;
int *m_array = nullptr;

public:
IntArray(int length):
    m_length(length)
{
    if (length <= 0)
        assert("IntArray length should be a positive integer");

    m_array = new int[m_length] { 0 };
}

// Copy constructor that does a deep copy
IntArray(const IntArray &array):
    m_length(array.m_length)
{
    // Allocate a new array
    m_array = new int[m_length];

    // Copy elements from original array to new array
    for (int count = 0; count < array.m_length; ++count)
        m_array[count] = array.m_array[count];
}

~IntArray()
{
    delete[] m_array;
}

// If you're getting crazy values here you probably forgot to do a deep copy in your copy constructor
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const IntArray &array)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < array.m_length; ++count)
    {
        std::cout << array.m_array[count] << ' ';
    }
    return out;
}

int& operator[] (const int index)
{
    assert(index >= 0);
    assert(index < m_length);
    return m_array[index];
}

// Assignment operator that does a deep copy
IntArray& operator= (const IntArray &array)
{
    // self-assignment guard
    if (this == &array)
        return *this;

    // If this array already exists, delete it so we don't leak memory
    delete[] m_array;

    m_length = array.m_length;

    // Allocate a new array
    m_array = new int[m_length];

    // Copy elements from original array to new array
    for (int count = 0; count < array.m_length; ++count)
        m_array[count] = array.m_array[count];

    return *this;
}

};

IntArray fillArray()
{
IntArray a(5);
a[0] = 5;
a[1] = 8;
a[2] = 2;
a[3] = 3;
a[4] = 6;

return a;
}

int main()
{
IntArray a = fillArray();

// If you're getting crazy values here you probably forgot to do a deep copy in your copy constructor
std::cout << a << '\n';

IntArray b(1);
a = a;
b = a;

 // If you're getting crazy values here you probably forgot to do a deep   copy in your assignment operator
// or you forgot your self-assignment check
std::cout << b << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

so im trying to understand this code. I know the copy constructor is going to be called for IntArray a = FillArray().  However I do not know how IntArray(const IntArray &array) works. I understand the syntax, but dont understand where array.m_length is coming from. Nor am I understanding how these values get returned to IntArray a.  Please help.

Comment: `b=a`  is equivalent to `b.operator=(a)`, so parameter named `array` is the right part of the assignment.

Comment: Yeah I have knowledge of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m_length` is a class member of type "int".

This code:

```
IntArray(const IntArray &array): m_length(array.m_length)
```

declares a function with one parameter named "array".  The semicolon denotes a constructor initializer list.  `m_length` is a class member called out to be constructed in this list.  `m_length` is an "int", so int's copy constructor is called automatically when this function is invoked.  `array.m_length` comes from "array" which is the argument being passed in your copy constructor.

Comment: so array.m_length in this instance would = 5. because it comes from FillArray()?

Comment: in the function FillArray(), an IntArray object is instantiated using the IntArray copy constructor and the argument passed in that copy constructor is the integer "5".  When the program gets into the copy constructor, in that instance, yes, array.m_length is 5.

Comment: so would it be wrong or bad programming going forward to presume that the the copy constructors parameters are being taken from the object being copied?

Comment: copy constructors always get their values from the objects being copied.  They are by definition a function that constructs an object, and that object is supposed to be a copy of another [already existing] object.

Comment: Any more questions or clarifications?  Otherwise I ask please upvote and accept my answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I understand the syntax, but dont understand where `array.m_length` is
>   coming from.

You are in the function `IntArray(const IntArray &array)`, so `array` is the reference parameter (i.e., the right hand side argument of the assignment/initialization), and `array.m_length` is the member variable `m_length` of the referenced `IntArray` object.

> Nor am I understanding how these values get returned to IntArray a.
>   Please help.

Again, in the copy constructor, you have the initialization of the member variable `m_length` (`:m_length(array.m_length`), and then the assignment of the member m_array:

```
// Allocate a new array
m_array = new int[m_length];
// Copy elements from original array to new array
for (int count = 0; count < array.m_length; ++count)
    m_array[count] = array.m_array[count];
```

which is how the values of the member variables of the array returned by `fillArray()` are assigned to the corresponding member variables of `a` when the statement `IntArray a = fillArray()` is executed.

Comment: and so when the copy constructor is called are the parameters of that constructor taken from the object being copied?

Comment: The copy constructor has one parameter, the object being copied. In your example:  a `const IntArray &`. What then happens is expressed in the code of the copy constructor. But yes, in your case (and also typically in general) what the copy ctor does is copy (the value of) each of the members of the object being copied. That is, use those values to initialize the members of the object being constructed.